# AWS Amplify API: Can't remove @key from a @model

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Using AWS Amplify, I finally removed the @key attribute of one of my models (I don't need it, I want an autogenerated UUID).

When doing a `amplify push` I get this error

```
Attempting to edit the key schema of the NewsTable table in the News stack. 
An error occured during the push operation: Attempting to edit the key schema of the NewsTable table in the News stack.
```

How can I force it ?
I don't mind losing data as it's not in production. I just don't want to hack it with a crappy rename or having to delete my whole App Sync project for this.

Comment: Quick hack I found: I added a dummy @model and totally deleted my News model from the schema.graphql. I pushed and it worked. Then I put back my News model and removed my dummy model (without the key). And it worked. But is this the real way to do it ?

Comment: I've pushed through with the exact same approach.  I don't disagree with it.  I've observed that I can always create a single new environment with a modified schema with the amplify cli and drop the existing prior one when the data in the prior environment is absolutely disposable. `amplify push` limitation comes from DynamoDB because GSIs are created when the DynamoDB table is created. A new environment is less work than a table migration, for sure.

Comment: By dummy model what do you mean? Just anything so that it does a push? If so why do you need that to remove the key? An example would be great.

Comment: I'll add a more detailled answer @PeteDuncanson

Answer (score 3):

**NOT FOR PRODUCTION. Be careful, this method erases all your data.**

Assuming you need to remove the key "licenceNumber" from the "Car" model

```
type Car @model {
  licenceNumber: String! @key
  color: String!
}
```

Push anything but remove that Car model

```
type Car_renamed_to_make_the_push_work @model {
  licenceNumber: String!
  color: String!
}
```

And then rename your model again, but without the key

```
type Car @model {
  licenceNumber: String!
  color: String!
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, really just like that! Interesting work around, thanks so much @maxime for taking the time to come back and flesh that out.